# Overriding storybook routes by next.js routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, storybook

Recently i have developed a `storybook`. Now, i want to attach it to another project which is developed using `next.js`. `Storybook` uses it's own routes whereas my `next.js` application has it's own routes. I want to manage all the routes using `next.js` and override storybook routes.

Let say my application runs at:

```
localhost:3000
```

and i want to add the storybook at

```
localhost:3000/storybook
```

How can i tell `next.js` that on this route a build of storybook is to be served or i can control the routes of `stroybook`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen, the recommendation is usually to run Storybook on another port locally. If you want your Storybook accessible to the public, I would recommend doing a URL like `storybook.your-site.com` or `ui.your-site.com`.

Related: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/5975